# Visual basic Problems reading DefaultUserName key value from the registry

Tags: vbscript

I wrote a vbscript some weeks ago to get the DefaultUserName key value of a remote computer. That scrip is working well. I am trying to do the same from a VB.net app and I am getting Nothing as result. I am also starting the same script from my vb application and I am getting the same. It looks like the script works well alone but not if a start it from the vb.net app. Bellow is the vb code I am using to get the registry value, that code also gets Nothing as result. Do I need to set something on the vb environment? What could be happening? Any help is appreciate. Thanks

```
Private Sub askComputer2(ByVal computer, ByRef text)
    Dim strKeyPath As String, strEntryName As String, comment As String, strValue As String
    'Dim objReg As Object
    Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
    strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
    strEntryName = "ReportBootOk"
    comment = ""
    strValue = ""
    'text = "Computer Name = " & computer & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

    On Error Resume Next

    Dim objReg As Object = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & computer & "\root\cimv2")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        text = "It was not possible to get Autologin information for " & computer & vbNewLine & "Error: " & Err.Number & "  Source: " & Err.Source & "  Description: " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear()
    Else
        'MsgBox(objReg.Value(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strEntryName, strValue).ToString())
        strValue = objReg.Value(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strEntryName, strValue).ToString()
        MsgBox(strValue)
        If strValue = "1" Then
            comment = " (Autologin machine)"
        ElseIf strValue = "0" Then
            comment = " (Non Autologin machine)"
        End If
        text = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\AutoAdminLogon = " & strValue & comment
        strEntryName = "DefaultUserName"
        objReg.GetStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, strEntryName, strValue)
        text = text & "  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\DefaultUserName = " & strValue
        MsgBox(text, , "Autologin Check")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: VB.net and vbscript are two completely different languages.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The question says "I am trying to do the same from a VB.net app and I am getting Nothing as result", so I assumed this was VB.NET related... but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running into [registry differences for 64-bit vs. 32-bit processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Keys under `HKLM\SOFTWARE` are read from `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` for 32-bit processes, leading to confusing results.  If you modify `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\DefaultUserName` using RegEdit, you should see that it is the value being read by your code.

You can read the 64-bit registry keys from a 32-bit (or 64-bit) process by using the [`RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey(v=vs.110).aspx) method with the appropriate `view` option (.NET 4.0+):

```
Dim hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)
Dim winlogon = hklm.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon")
Dim val = winlogon.GetValue("DefaultUserName")
Console.WriteLine(val)
```

Comment: Thanks Marl, I am getting a little bit frustrated :( , I also tried with the code bellow but it also failed...

Comment: MsgBox(computer)
        Dim environmentKey As RegistryKey
        Dim text1 As String
        environmentKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, computer).OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", False)

        text = CStr(environmentKey.GetValue("DefaultUserName", "?"))
        MsgBox(text)

Comment: @JCNunez If you are opening a remote registry, you need to use the overload that [takes a `RegistryView` parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd411615%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - `RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, computer, RegistryView.Registry64)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mark I could get this code. It will be able to get the AutoAdminLogon and DefaultUserName registry values of any computer on the network

```
 Private Sub askComputer1(ByVal computer)

    MsgBox(computer)
    Dim environmentKey As RegistryKey
    Dim val1 As String, val2 As String
    environmentKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, computer, RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon")

    val1 = environmentKey.GetValue("AutoAdminLogon").ToString()
    val2 = environmentKey.GetValue("DefaultUserName").ToString()
    MsgBox(val1 & "   " & val2)
    environmentKey.Close()

End Sub
```